# Uses for differentiating under the integral sign

Tags: calculus, integration, leibniz-integral-rule

Where is differentiating under the integral sign useful and where is it used? What are some sources that explain this well? I'm doing some reading and a little confused.

Comment: Just read [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf) and it will explain everything

Comment: What are you reading? Does it use differentiating under the integral but not explain it? Or does it try to explain it but you aren't getting it?

Comment: http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf

Comment: "Advanced Calculus" by Buck actually has a section of exercises (and a number of examples) of this technique, illustrating how to prove uniform convergence of certain integrals and how this hypothesis allows the use of differentiation under the integral sign. If you're familiar with measure theory, the link provided by @CountIblis gives a more general formulation.

Comment: I read about it in a book by Richard feynman and he talked about how it's not empathized in university and how it's a tool he used often, so I want to know where it's used? I understand the steps behind it but where is it used?

Comment: I always say "differentiating through the integral sign", rathere than "under". However it is a campaign that has attracted a pitiable number of supporters.